# prepared statement in stored procedure not refreshing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Using a dynamically created view WITHIN a Loop in this MySQL stored procedure. The problem I'm having is the contents of `temp_controller_view` view only reflect the result from the view's first creation (e.g. first loop) as if the statement `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` isn't being read.

Obviously I'm trying to get the view to update upon each Looping so that I can work with the contents of the dynamic view

MYSQL @@VERSION >  5.1.61

```
DROP procedure if exists SITETOEPRISE;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SITETOEPRISE()
BEGIN
  DECLARE bDone INT;

  DECLARE sid int(11);    -- or approriate type
  DECLARE curr_site_db VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE Var3 VARCHAR(50);

  DECLARE site_curs CURSOR FOR SELECT siteid FROM sites;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

  OPEN site_curs;

  SET bDone = 0;

  site_loop : LOOP

  FETCH site_curs INTO sid;

  IF bDone THEN
    CLOSE site_curs;
    LEAVE site_loop;
  END IF;

  select sid as 'sid_in_loop';

  SET @dyn_sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `temp_controller_view` AS SELECT * from site',sid,'.controller;');
  select @dyn_sql;
  PREPARE stmt_dyn_view FROM @dyn_sql;
  EXECUTE stmt_dyn_view;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_dyn_view;

  select * from temp_controller_view;

  drop view temp_controller_view;

  END LOOP;

END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL server? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: MYSQL @@VERSION > 5.1.61